# Play video instead of download it. Js/HTML5 not playing video with scr="myvideolink.mp4"

Tags: javascript, c#, html, reactjs, video

I have the following link:

http://cdnv2.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCServer01/videos/STHPRKT02EP01.mp4

I'm trying to embed it in an application that i'm writing in React.

I have tried using HTML5 video tag and [video-react](https://video-react.js.org), but instead of playing the file it downloads right away... I made a test in C# (winforms) with Windows Media Player Component and it plays normally.

Here some source I've tried:

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="http://cdnv2.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCServer01/videos/STHPRKT02EP01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```html
    <video src="http://cdnv2.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCServer01/videos/STHPRKT02EP01.mp4" controls>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Player } from 'video-react';

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Player
      playsInline
      src="http://cdnv2.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCServer01/videos/STHPRKT02EP01.mp4"
    />
  );
};
```

Is there a way to play this link on the browser with only js or some client-side script?

Comment: what you have tried? show some code.. try using JSfiddle.com / https://codesandbox.io etc..

Comment: Not an expert but if you got the video syntax correct and I had to guess, it could be your encoding. You may need to convert it from mp4 to ogg or webm.

Comment: Added some sample code. @Vishantdhandha

Comment: @Crowcoder the thing is, I wanna set the src of the video directly from that url, and as you can see from the snippet, it doesn't appear to work, and when I use the component of React and load the page it starts do download the video instead of playing.

Comment: Your server is probably sending the wrong mime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl -I http://cdnv2.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCServer01/videos/STHPRKT02EP01.mp4` shows that your server has a MIME type of `video/x-flv` for your video. You want it to be `video/mp4`

in IIS you can adjust that either with a web.config file, or:

- Right-click the site in IIS and select Properties.
- Select the HTTP Headers Tab.
- Select File Types.
- Under the MIME Map section, select New Type.
- Type ".mp4" as the associated extension and "video/mp4" as the content type.
- Click OK.